# Analogies for integral theorems of vector calculus?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, intuition

The reason I'm asking for analogies is because I find myself just doing computation but not having an idea of what I'm actually doing.

For example, I know there is an analogy for line integrals as building a fence, where the height of each board is given by the value of $f(x,y)$ from the line segment underneath. (The limitation would be that that the line would need to be on a flat surface) And I suppose surface integrals would be building boxes on top of a surface, where the volume of the box depends on where it is  on the polyhedral approximation of the surface... but I don't need help on line or surface integrals.

But what would be analogies for Green's, Stokes' and Divergence/Gauss' theorems? All the books I've looked at just seem to restate the equation in word form and using the idea of a flow rather than vectors, but nothing that reframes the ideas into something that one might understand without looking at the specific equations or would intuitively understand without having studied the material already.

Comment: Are you looking for analogies of the theorems themselves or for the integrals (line/surface/volume)? Anyway, all the integral theorems are saying that "behavior of the derivative inside is related to what happens on the boundary", and this is also precisely what the single-variable FTC tells us: $\int_a^bf'=f(b)-f(a)$.

Comment: It's the theorems themselves. I do know about generalized Stokes theorem, in how it describes what you have mentioned in quotations. But I'm still wondering what the analogies are for Green's, Stokes', and Gauss' theorems.

Comment: @MathBoi have you seen Kahn academy's videos (on yt) about Stokes and Gauss's theorems? In my opinion those videos give a very good phyisical intuition behind it (I guess that is what you are looking for)

Comment: The standard interpretation of Stokes' theorem as integrating circulation density (curl) over a region to get circulation around the boundary and of Gauss' theorem as integrating flux density (divergence) over a region to get outward flux through the boundary (in both cases taking advantage of internal cancellations) are the most intuitive interpretations I've seen. Are these the ones that you have seen and found unsatisfactory? If so, I don't think there are any other "more intuitive" interpretations out there.